# Search inside full search column using certain letters

Tags: crate

I want to search inside a full search column using certain letters, I mean:

```
select "Name","Country","_score" from datatable where match("Country", 'China');
```

Returns many rows and is ok. My question is, how can I search for example:

```
select "Name","Country","_score" from datatable where match("Country", 'Ch');
```

I want to see, China, Chile, etc.

I think that match_type phrase_prefix can be the answer, but I don't know how I can use (correct syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match predicate supports different types by use of `using match_type [with (match_parameter = [value])]`.

So in your example using the `phrase_prefix` match type:

`select "Name","Country","_score" from datatable where match("Country", 'Ch') using phrase_prefix;`

gives you your desired results.

See the `match predicate` documentation: https://crate.io/docs/en/latest/sql/fulltext.html?#match-predicate

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to match the beginning of a string column, you don't need a fulltext analyzed column. You can use the [LIKE operator](https://crate.io/docs/en/latest/sql/queries.html#like) instead, e.g.:

```
cr> create table names_table (name string, country string);
CREATE OK (0.840 sec)

cr> insert into names_table (name, country) values ('foo', 'China'), ('bar','Chile'), ('foobar', 'Austria');
INSERT OK, 3 rows affected (0.049 sec)

cr> select * from names_table where country like 'Ch%';
+---------+------+
| country | name |
+---------+------+
| Chile   | bar  |
| China   | foo  |
+---------+------+
SELECT 2 rows in set (0.037 sec)
```

Comment: I want to use a very long column (more than 100000 records, so, the fulltest analyzed looks like good. Thanks for the suggestion.